# R 3-dimensional dynamic array

Tags: arrays, r

I know the lenghts of 2 out of the 3 dimensions of an array. The third dimension has to grow depending on the lines read in a file.

For example, if the first 2 dimensions are 3x3, I want to initialize a matrix in R with empty arrays, like this:

```
M = 

c() c() c()

c() c() c()

c() c() c()
```

And then insert elements like: `M[1][1] = c(M[1][1], newElem)`

I tried a lot of different things but I didn't succeed.

Comment: It is not clear what you do and why you do it. So, I can't really advice if your intended approach is sensible. However, you could use `abind` (from package abind) to grow the array. Obviously, this will be slow if you do it repeatedly (like in a loop).

Comment: I think I can solve my problem if I discover how to put a vector inside a vector in R. I cannot do something like:

a = c(1,2), b = c(3,4,5), matrix = c(a,b).
Now if you want to access like: matrix[2] you don't get b, you get 2

Comment: I have no idea what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: In the example above, I want to create a vector V that contains A and B, so if you access V like this: V[1] you get the vector A and V[1][1] returns the first element of A (1 in this case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want lists (which are the only data structure that can contain any combination of any types of objects in R):

```
a <- c(1,2) 
b <- c(3,4,5)
mylist <- list(a,b)
mylist[[2]]
#[1] 3 4 5
mylist[[2]][2]
#[1] 4
```

Comment: Good! That's what I wanted, finally! I didn't remember lists :(  Thank you very much!